# How can I wait until an application has started?

Tags: bash, scripts

In a Bash script, how can I wait until an application is open?

**Example:**

```
#!/bin/bash

# wait until Thunderbird open to then close its main window...
wmctrl -c "Mozilla Thunderbird"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic answer is that you have to monitor list of open windows for change. You can do so in number of ways, but since you're using `wmctrl` you can use that like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
    # get list of windows
    windows=$(wmctrl -l)
    # check if window is on the list
    if [[ "$windows" =~ "Mozilla Firefox" ]];
    then
         echo "found firefox, closing it  in 3 seconds"
         sleep 3 
         wmctrl -c "Mozilla Firefox"
    fi
    # delay until next loop iteration
    sleep 3
done
```

Since you've also requested example for looping until the specific window closes, here's an edited example with alternative looping approach ( which would probably be preferred; at least that's the structure I personally use quite a lot):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script enters into this while loop, and keeps checking
# if wmctrl -l lists firefox. Condition is true if firefox
# isn't there. When firefox appears, condition is false,
# loop exits
while ! [[ "$(wmctrl -l)" =~ "Mozilla Firefox" ]] 
do
    # number of seconds can be changed for better precision
    # but shorter time equals more pressure on CPU
    sleep 3
done

# Only after firefox appears , we get to here
echo "found firefox, closing it  in 3 seconds"
sleep 3 
wmctrl -c "Mozilla Firefox"

# Same idea as before - we enter the waiting loop,
# and keep looping until firefox is not on the list
windows=$(wmctrl -l)
while  [[ "$(wmctrl -l)" =~ "Mozilla Firefox" ]] 
do
    sleep 3
done
#When loop exits, that means firefox isn't on the list
echo "Script is done"
```

Comment: Thank you, Serg! Can the script automatically terminate once the window is closed?

Comment: @orschiro yes, that can be done with another loop. I'll edit my answer soon

Comment: @orschiro done, answer edited, with a lot of comments explaining what's being done